# ajax in laravel -post method not allowed (405 error)

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

I want to get the value in ajax response to populate the value in select box
I have fetched the field value and send to other page using ajax.In console I caught `POST http://localhost/pject_name/public/ajaxteach 405 (Method Not Allowed)`but When I the url in network it prints 'test connection'.How to get response in ajax call

```
$('#name-first').on('change',function(){
          dataString=$('#name-first').val();
        $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url : "{{url('ajaxteach')}}",
                data : dataString,
                success : function(data){
                    console.log(data);
                },error: function () {
             alert('Erreur. Veuillez réessayer.');
          } 
      });
     });
route
  Route::get('/ajaxteach', array(
   'as' => 'ajaxteach',
   'uses' => 'assetRequestController@getproject'
  ) );
controller
public function getproject(Request $request){
print_r($request->dataString);
     echo 'test connection';
}
```

Comment: your type should be `GET` not `POST`

Comment: Route::post('/ajaxteach', array(
   'as' => 'ajaxteach',
   'uses' => 'assetRequestController@getproject'
  ) );

Comment: Try to change `type: "POST",` to `type: "GET",`

Comment: tried post.caught MethodNotAllowedHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 218:

Comment: Change only to `type: "GET"` in your ajax call!

Answer (score 0):

Here is the official list of HTTP response codes. https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html

a 405 error means you used the wrong `HTTP method`. I can see you sent a `POST`, so most likely it is looking for a `GET` request, although it could be one of the others like PUT PATCH DELETE etc (although unlikely).

Answer (score 0):

You have used GET method in the AJAX function and used POST in the route. As Delboy said you get 405 error when you used wrong HTTP method. This should work when you change the route to POST like this.

```
  Route::post('/ajaxteach', array(
  'as' => 'ajaxteach',
  'uses' => 'assetRequestController@getproject'
  ));
```